# How to uninstall software from outside the software manager in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, uninstall, gui

Its hypothetical question for me.
But i installed seam trough the website and not the software manager
How do i uninstall it (preferably using gui only)

Comment: When you installed "through the website", what commands  did you use in Terminal?? **Edit the question** to add needed information.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic package manager will help to remove it using gui

Just run

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

in terminal

https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/

Comment: Only if the software has been installed using .deb packages. With the information given so far you know nothing about what specific software the OP is talking about nor how they were installed. It can be SNAP, Flatpak, or others.

Comment: Op probably went to steam website, downloaded the deb file and installed it that way